# Signalling boolean over datetime interval in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I got a pretty straightforward problem and there must be a simple way to solve such problem. Consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
start = pd.Timestamp('2013-08-14T00:00')
end = pd.Timestamp('2013-08-15T00:00')
t = np.linspace(start.value, end.value, 60*60*24+1)
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(t)
```

Now I want to create one column  `df['Action']` which is a boolean, signalling true for intervals of 5s. So as outcome, I expect something like this:

```
            Timestamp          Action      
0     2013-08-14 00:00:00        False          
1     2013-08-14 00:00:01        False  
2     2013-08-14 00:00:02        False
3     2013-08-14 00:00:03        False
4     2013-08-14 00:00:04        False
5     2013-08-14 00:00:05        True
6     2013-08-14 00:00:06        False
7     2013-08-14 00:00:07        False
8     2013-08-14 00:00:08        False
9     2013-08-14 00:00:09        False
10     2013-08-14 00:00:10       True
11     2013-08-14 00:00:11       False
```

Yes, I could play with the index however that doesn't seem really elegant. I also want to be able to adjust the interval for different inputs.

Hope that I managed to be succinct and precise. I would really appreciate your help on this one!

Comment: So it is always one second intervals between consecutive rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`Series.dt.second`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.second.html) and check the rest of the division with 5,
this is faster, see comparison of times:

```
df['Action']=(df['Timestamp'].dt.second % 5).eq(0)
print(df.head(21))
```

**Output**

```
             Timestamp  Action
0  2013-08-14 00:00:00    True
1  2013-08-14 00:00:01   False
2  2013-08-14 00:00:02   False
3  2013-08-14 00:00:03   False
4  2013-08-14 00:00:04   False
5  2013-08-14 00:00:05    True
6  2013-08-14 00:00:06   False
7  2013-08-14 00:00:07   False
8  2013-08-14 00:00:08   False
9  2013-08-14 00:00:09   False
10 2013-08-14 00:00:10    True
11 2013-08-14 00:00:11   False
12 2013-08-14 00:00:12   False
13 2013-08-14 00:00:13   False
14 2013-08-14 00:00:14   False
15 2013-08-14 00:00:15    True
16 2013-08-14 00:00:16   False
17 2013-08-14 00:00:17   False
18 2013-08-14 00:00:18   False
19 2013-08-14 00:00:19   False
20 2013-08-14 00:00:20    True
```

If you want set to `False` the first value:

```
df.at[0,'Action']=False
```

---

**time comparison**

```
%%timeit
df['Action']=(df['Timestamp'].dt.second%5).eq(0)
10.8 ms ± 99.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
dt_range = pd.date_range(df['Timestamp'].iloc[0], 
                         df['Timestamp'].iloc[-1], 
                         freq='5s')
df['Action'] = df['Timestamp'].isin(dt_range)
23.9 ms ± 7.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.date_range` to create a list of all values you want to map to `True`:

```py
dt_range = pd.date_range(df['Timestamp'].iloc[0], 
                         df['Timestamp'].iloc[-1], 
                         freq='5s')
df['Action'] = df['Timestamp'].isin(dt_range)
print(df.head(12))
```

```
             Timestamp  Action
0  2013-08-14 00:00:00    True
1  2013-08-14 00:00:01   False
2  2013-08-14 00:00:02   False
3  2013-08-14 00:00:03   False
4  2013-08-14 00:00:04   False
5  2013-08-14 00:00:05    True
6  2013-08-14 00:00:06   False
7  2013-08-14 00:00:07   False
8  2013-08-14 00:00:08   False
9  2013-08-14 00:00:09   False
10 2013-08-14 00:00:10    True
11 2013-08-14 00:00:11   False
```